# Duvida sobre Filtro - JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

bom estou aprendendo JSP e estou tentando fazer um filtro onde o usuário não estiver logado ele redireciona para uma página de login, e não estou conseguindo.

OBS: Criei uma Servlet controladora que faz o Dispacher para uma JSP, no Caso seria **AdicionaTarefa** e **ListarTarefaLogic** e essas Logicas possui o retorno para uma Página JSP que está dentro de **WEB-INF/jsp/view**

Ao tentar acessar uma Lógica pela URL ex: mvc?logica=AdicionaTarefa ele está redirecionando para mvc?logica=TelaDeLogin "Até aqui OK", só que não aparece minha página.

@WebServlet("/mvc")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String parametro = request.getParameter("logica");

    if(parametro == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Falta passar o parametro.");
    }
    try {
        String nomeDaClasse = "br.com.triadworks.todoList.logica." + parametro;
        Class<?> classe = Class.forName(nomeDaClasse);
        Logica logica = (Logica) classe.newInstance();
        String pagina = logica.executa(request, response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(pagina).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("A lógica causou uma exceção!", e);
    }
}
```

}

public interface Logica {

```
String executa(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;
```

}

public class AdicionaTarefa implements Logica {

```
@Override
public String executa(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("usuarioLogado") != null) {

        Connection connection = (Connection) request.getAttribute("connection");

        List<Usuario> usuarios = new UsuarioDAO(connection).buscarTodosUsuarios();
        List<Situacao> statusSituacao = Arrays.asList(Situacao.values());

        request.setAttribute("usuarios", usuarios);
        request.setAttribute("statusTarefas", statusSituacao);

        return "WEB-INF/jsp/view/adicionar.jsp";

    }
    return "mvc?logica=TelaLogin";
}
```

}

public class LoginTarefaLogic implements Logica {

```
@Override
public String executa(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = (Connection) request.getAttribute("connection");

    String login = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String senha = request.getParameter("senha");

    Usuario usuarioAutenticado = new UsuarioDAO(connection).autenticar(new Usuario(login, senha));

    if (usuarioAutenticado != null) {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
        pegaSessaoUsuario(request, usuarioAutenticado);
        return "mvc?logica=AdicionaTarefa";
    } else {
        return "mvc?logica=TelaLogin";
    }
}

public static void pegaSessaoUsuario(HttpServletRequest request, Usuario usuarioAutenticado) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuarioAutenticado);
    System.out.println("Usuario: " +usuarioAutenticado.getNome() + "ID" + usuarioAutenticado.getId() + "senha: " +usuarioAutenticado.getSenha());
}
```

}

Filter

```
@WebFilter("/todoList/*")
```

public class FilterAutenticador implements Filter {

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (verificaUsuarioLogado((HttpServletRequest) request)){
        System.out.println("verficando....");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }else{
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
}

private boolean verificaUsuarioLogado(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {

    if (servletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("usuarioLogado") != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Posta o código da Servlet que chama o JSP da tela de login.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei a tela de Login onde é guardado a Session do usuario, neste caso está funcionando normalmente. No caso da Logica **AdicionaTarefa ** estou fazendo se existe session para continuar acessado, minha duvida é usar o FIlter.

Comment: Seu filtro aparentemente está correto com relação ao redirect. Eu vou postar um filtro que tenho e que funciona muito bem.
Pode ser que ao dar o redirect, ele entra no filto de novo e de novo e de novo, já que a o urlPattern está para /*

Answer (score 0):

O código parece um pouco confuso com relação ao que você quer fazer.
Pelo que eu entendi...

Você quer um filtro no padrão de URL /* só que existem algumas funções em /* que não necessitam de login.
Se for o caso, muda a url para outra e faz o mapeamento novamente. Exemplo:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "FilterLoggedIn", urlPatterns = {"/dash/*"}, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.INCLUDE})
public class FilterLoggedIn implements Filter {

public boolean doBeforeProcessing(HttpServletRequest req) {

        if (req.getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (doBeforeProcessing((HttpServletRequest) request)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
            resp.sendError(401);
        }

    }

}
```

Obviamente, no seu caso vai trocar o `resp.sendError` para `sendRedirect`, e  o URL passado como parametro deve ser diferente de `dash/*` para que o filtro não tente capturar a requisição de novo.

Se ficar mais alguma dúvida, pode comentar.

Abraços.

Comment: Esses  DispatcherType não é reconhecida.

Comment: É da especificação Servlet 3.1. Tente remover ou procurar algo equivalente a sua versão.

Comment: coloquei assim, nada ainda..